# Positional Operator Matching Nested Arrays Workaround?

Tags: mongodb

As was just pointed out to me on stackoverflow, [Positional Operator Matching Nested Arrays](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) has yet to be made available..

**I need to display read.marked:true replies differently than read.marked:false replies, dependent on each particular user's marking.**

This findOneAndUpdate is contained by a loop that runs through each of the replies..is there a workaround for making updates to each reply for a particular user in the 'to' array?

I can capture each replies._id, or each replies.to._id

Right now, MongoDB produces this: [MongoError: cannot use the part (to of replies.0.to.read.marked) to traverse the element..] ..when it should really look something like this anyways: replies.$.to.$.read.marked

```
Models.Message.findOneAndUpdate(

  { "replies._id": ObjectId("53dd4b67f0f23cad267f9d8b"), "replies.to.username": "UserA" },
  {
    "$set": { 
        "replies.$.to.read.marked": true,
        "replies.$.to.read.datetime": req.body.datetimeRead,
        "replies.$.to.updated": req.body.datetimeRead
    }
  },
```

To $set to.read.marked:true for userA of the specific reply:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53daf26af7b70fd82ffd4cff"),
    "updated" : ISODate("2014-08-02T20:36:03.000Z"),
    "message" : "here's a message",
    "replies" : [ 
        {
            "reply" : "here's a reply",
            "created" : 1407011687000,
            "_id" : ObjectId("53dd4b67f0f23cad267f9d8b"),
            "to" : [ 
                {
                    "username" : "userA",
                    "updated" : ISODate("2014-08-02T20:34:47.000Z"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53dd4b67f0f23cad267f9d8c"),
                    "read" : {
                        "datetime" : ISODate("2014-08-02T20:34:47.000Z"),
                        "marked" : false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "username" : "userB",
                    "updated" : ISODate("2014-08-02T20:34:47.000Z"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53dd4b67f0f23cad267f9d8d"),
                    "read" : {
                        "datetime" : ISODate("2014-08-02T20:34:47.000Z"),
                        "marked" : false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "reply" : "here's another reply",
            "created" : 1407011763000,
            "_id" : ObjectId("53dd4bb3a9f9497e270525cb"),
            "to" : [ 
                {
                    "username" : "userA",
                    "updated" : ISODate("2014-08-02T20:36:03.000Z"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53dd4bb3a9f9497e270525cc"),
                    "read" : {
                        "datetime" : ISODate("2014-08-02T20:36:03.000Z"),
                        "marked" : false
                    }
                },
                {
                    "username" : "userB",
                    "updated" : ISODate("2014-08-02T20:36:03.000Z"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("53dd4bb3a9f9497e270525cd"),
                    "read" : {
                        "datetime" : ISODate("2014-08-02T20:36:03.000Z"),
                        "marked" : false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: I take for granted that you can not change the Message model? Since there are several problems with your approach. If the message model can be changed, your problem becomes rather trivial.

Comment: @PaulWhite wouldn't that be a little off-topic here? Thought data modeling questions would be more suited for SO, hence I just commented.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg No, data modelling is [explicitly on-topic here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).